# jquery mobile popup doesn't wait for a click

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

Using jquery mobile 1.2, I have a popup menu (OK/Cancel) which should be answered before changing to a new page. But the page changes (and the popup disappears) before it is clicked:

```
if (rider.time.valueOf() > 0) {
    $('#popupMsg').text("Rider has already finished; update the time?");
    $('#alreadyFinished').popup("open");
}
alert("rf");
// other code.......
$.mobile.changePage("#finishLine");
// other code.......
```

I put in the 'alert' just to prove that the popup does actually appear - there it is, behind the alert, but the popup closes (and the page changes) as soon as the alert is clicked. Also tried removing the 'other code' but still the same problem.

Here's the html:

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="alreadyFinished" class="ui-content">
         <p id="popupMsg"></p>
         <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="OKBtn">OK</a>
         <a href="#finishLine" data-role="button" data-theme="c"  id="cancelBtn">Cancel</a>
     </div>
```

Even without the buttons in the popup, the popup doesn't persist. So what's wrong?

Comment: This code is not enough, please show us more. Unless your changePage function is bind to the button OKBtn it will changePage whatever you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jQuery Mobile popup is part of a page. Changing the page will close any current popup, so you should not directly call it following the opening of a popup. The following code would open your popup and not close it.

```
if (rider.time.valueOf() > 0) {
    $('#popupMsg').text("Rider has already finished; update the time?");
    $('#alreadyFinished').popup("open");
} else {
    alert("rf");
    // other code.......
    $.mobile.changePage("#finishLine");
// other code.......
}
```

If you want your popup to be modal, the simplest way is to bind the execution of the rest of your code to the closing of the popup. For instance, if you want the `restOfCode` function to be run after the popup is closed:

```
$('#alreadyFinished').popup("open");
$( "#alreadyFinished" ).on({
   popupafterclose: function(event, ui) {restOfCode()}
});
```

Comment: I was trying to use a popup ina  modal way, as something nicer than an 'alert'. This code does what I want but doesn't look as nice:

Comment: Sorry, Romain and @Gajotres,that was posted before I finished editing. I was trying to use a popup as a modal dialog, but I assume then that it can't be done. Uisng 'result = confirm("...?")' does the job but doesn't look as nice and is different across platforms. I know I can use a dialog but that fills the whole page

Comment: Right, thanks, that makes it modal so you've answered my question! But now need to work out how to do a different {restofCode} depending on which button (OK or Cancel) was clicked in the popup....

Comment: you can just bind your code to the buttons of the popup, in which case you might want to unbind the popupafterclose event. Fyi, JQM 1.3.0 now has  a "dismissible" option for popups that you will find useful

Comment: Of course, seems obvious now. Clearly I've had too long creating event handlers the lazy way using MS VisualStudio and C#. And JQM 1.3 looks great, good to see the technology evolving so quickly.